# Prevent anonymous users from seeing agile boards

Tags: jira, greenhopper

Is there a way to prevent anonymous user from seeing agile boards in greenhopper? I have checked global permissions but did not find anything that would allow me to limit board visibility.

Thank you.

Comment: I think GH uses the same permission scheme that the underlying JIRA project uses, so check out the Browse Projects permission in that permission scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to stop the Agile menu from appearing at all.

However, if you're trying to stop the Planning/Task/Chart/Released boards from being accessed by anonymous users that can be achieved by limiting the Browse Project permission.

If you'd like to stop Rapid Boards being visible to anonymous users, check the permissions on the Saved Filter used by the boards. A Rapid Board can only be seen by users with permissions to see the saved filter.

Thanks,
Shaun

Answer (score 0):

As Shaun said the solution was who the filter was shared with. Changing it to share only with authorized users would hide it from anonymous users.

[image]